# Spoof TCP SYN_ACK with another host

Tags: tcp

A normal SYN is received by hostA from client in the TCP three way hand shake routine.
After receiving SYN, is it possible to tell hostB to reply the SYN_ACK instead of hostA?

If it is impossible, is there any way or key words to transfer the traffic from hostA to hostB without alerting to client?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

No. It's not. Not unless you have complete control of the network routing infrastructure upstream of the "victim" PC.

Without that control, it is IMPOSSIBLE to spoof the full three-way handshake.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, we would like to spoof a http response. Instead of spoofing the three-way handshake, could we tell hostB to send the response which is supposed to be sent by hostA? In this manner, hostA is going to tell hostB all of the TCP information between hostA and the client. Is hostB possible to spoof a TCP response to the client?